# Smart way of converting dictionary to key=value connection string in python

Tags: python

I have always changing connection strings, with a variable number of keys such as port, timeout etc etc. I store these in a dictionary because I like to use that and it feels natural, but what I would like to do is convert something which looks like:

```
{'host':'localhost', 'user':'postgres', 'password':'xx', 'database':'test', 'socket_timeout':9999, 'ssl':False, 'port':5432}
```

into

something I can insert in place of this:

```
conn = DBAPI.connect(host=str(dbsettings['host']), user=(dbsettings['user']), password=str(dbsettings['password']), database=str(dbsettings['database']), ssl=dbsettings['ssl'], port=dbsettings['port'])
```

I can build a string a process with the following:

```
m = [str(k) + "=" + str(v) for k, v in dbsettings.items()]
```

but this feels like I'm not getting ahead. How can I retain the k as the keyword and v as the string and build a series of relations.

Comment: What would you do with this string once you created it? The `connect` method doesn't take a string representation of a bunch of comma-separated equals-connect keyword and value pairs, it takes a bunch of equals-connected keyword value pairs. Just as the string `'2'` isn't the same thing as the number `2`, the single argument `'host="my.host", user="me"'` isn't the same thing as the two argumetns `host="my.host"` and `user="me"`.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks but I do know that. That's why I said I'm not getting any further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to build a string here *at all*; retain your dictionary *as is* and use the `**kwargs` call syntax instead:

```
conn = DBAPI.connect(**dbsettings)
```

This passes each key-value pair in `dbsettings` as a keyword argument to the `DBAPI.connect()` function.